# Using moment-timezone in node.js

Tags: node.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

When trying to use a date from a specific timezone a I got the following error:

`const dayInGermany =  moment().tz("2020-01-31 13:00", "Europe/Berlin").toISOString();`

`Moment Timezone has no data for 2020-01-31 13:00. See http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/.`

The page https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/ says:

```
In Node.js, all the data is preloaded. No additional code is needed for loading data.
```

How can I add the timezone data to my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a small error.

Given

`const moment = require('moment-timezone');`

it should be

`const dayInGermany =  moment.tz("2020-01-31 13:00", "Europe/Berlin").toISOString();`

not

`const dayInGermany =  moment().tz("2020-01-31 13:00", "Europe/Berlin").toISOString();`